# Unable to execute pdf2txt.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdfminer

Trying to convert pdf files to txt in a windows environment using pdfminer per this write up: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167

I downloaded pdfminer and ran the setup.py successfully. I am unable to run pip install as the system does not have connectivity to the Internet.

When I execute the following command from C:\Python27

```
C:\python Tools\pdf2txt.py -o test.txt sample.pdf
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named pdfminer.pdfdocument
```

I tried copying the pdfdocument.py file to the Python27\Tools dir but still get the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: This error says exactly that python instalation does not know if and where pdfminer is installed. So you downloaded pdfminer as an archive like `pdfminer.tar.gz` or so. Did you try `sudo pip install <path_to_/pdfminer.tar.gz>`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am running on Windows 7. I had put the pdfminer folder inside the Python27 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing dependency:

```
$ pip install pdfminer
```